# Statistical Report(s) on Children of ConvertForMarriage+Born-Jewish Parents

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, children-parenting, statistics

Does anyone have/know where to find statistical reports on children of (1 Jewish Spouse + 1 Converted-to-Judaism-Mostly-For-Marriage Spouse) and their maintaining a Jewish connection?
I am having a really hard time finding this specific case on Google.
Thanks!
#Conversionary in-marriage, #Dor L'Dor, #Maintaining A Jewish Connection

Comment: Have you checked the Pew Research Center study "A Portrait of Jewish Americans" that came out a number of years ago? https://www.pewforum.org/2013/10/01/jewish-american-beliefs-attitudes-culture-survey/

Comment: Thank you! That is somewhat helpful. It doesn't specifically talk about people who converted for marriage, but it is helpful to look at the 2 most similar categories: intermarriage, and the inclusive category of Jews marrying Jews (which, as you know, includes those who convert for marriage). I do appreciate all of the statistics. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One paper that mentions this group of people is "The Facts about Intermarriage" in "Journal of Jewish Identities" by  Ira M. Sheskin and Harriet Hartman

To find more, google by using the quotations around the phrase "in-conversionary marriage" to ensure that the entire phrase is searched.